# Prove for any natural number $n$, ${a^n}$ + ${b^n}$ is a natural number not divisible by $5$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, algebraic-number-theory, natural-numbers

> Let $a = 3 + 2\sqrt{2}$ and $b = 3 - 2\sqrt{2}$. Prove that for every natural number $n$, ${a^n}$ + ${b^n}$ is a natural number, not divisible by $5$.

It's trivial that this number is natural by using binomial formula, but I can't figure out how to prove that it's not divisible by $5$.

Comment: Hint:  show that $s_n=a^n+b^n$ satisfies the recursion $s_n=6s_{n-1}-s_{n-2}$ with initial values $s_0=2, s_1=6$.  Show that this is periodic $\pmod 5$ and that the cycle does not contain $0$.  Note:  this also provides an alternate way to show that all the $s_n$ are natural numberts.

Comment: @lulu Great! You can even consider the recurrence already $(\text{mod }5)$ $$s'_n=s'_{n-1}-s_{n-2};\;s'_0=2;\;s'_1=1$$ and get directly the remainders that are never zero.

Answer (score 1):

I am well aware that what follows is **not** the simplest way to answer to this question, but I'd like to put the problem in a more structured context.

Consider the field
$$
\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)=\{a+b\sqrt2\,\mid\,a, b\in\Bbb Q\}.
$$
The field is endowed with an automorphism $\sigma$ defined as $\sigma(a+b\sqrt2)=a-b\sqrt2$ which has the property that $\Bbb Q$ is (the subfield) fixed.

Note that the two elements given are
$$
x=3+2\sqrt2\qquad\text{and}\qquad
x_\sigma=\sigma(x)=3-2\sqrt2
$$
This tells immediately that $x^n+x_\sigma^n\in\Bbb Q$ since $\sigma(x^n+x_\sigma^n)=x^n+x_\sigma^n$. Then it is pretty clear that it is actually in $\Bbb Z$ since taking positive powers never introduces denominators.

Next observe that $xx^\sigma=1$ so that in fact
$$
x^n+x^n_\sigma=\frac{1+x^{2n}}{x^n}\qquad\qquad(\ast)
$$
We now want to study divisibility by $5$. Thus we shall work modulo $5$ in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt 2]$. One has
$$
\frac{\Bbb Z[\sqrt 2]}{(5)}\simeq\frac{\Bbb Z[T]}{(5,T^2-2)}\simeq
\frac{\Bbb F_5[T]}{(T^2-2)}\simeq\Bbb F_{25},\qquad(\ast\ast)
$$
the field with $5^2$ elements, since $2$ is not a square modulo $5$.
Denote $\bar z$ the class of $z\in\Bbb Z[\sqrt2]$ in this quotient.

Note that $\bar x\neq0$ so that $\bar x^n\neq 0$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z$ so that after $(\ast)$ we need to prove that $\bar x^{2n}\neq-1$.

Now if $u=\bar T$ in $(\ast\ast)$ we can write $\bar x=3+2u$ and a simple modulo $5$ computation shows that $\bar x^2=-\bar x_\sigma$, i.e.
$$
\bar x^3=-1.
$$
Thus $\bar x^6=1$ and therefore
$$
\bar x^k=-1\qquad\Longleftrightarrow\qquad k\equiv3\bmod 6
$$
showing that the numerator of $(\ast)$ is never $0$ modulo $5$.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the hint in the great @lulu comment we have that
$$\left(3-2 \sqrt{2}\right)^n+ \left(2 \sqrt{2}+3\right)^n$$
is the solution of the recurrence having characteristic polynomial
$$\lambda^2-6\lambda+1$$
generated by the recurrence
$$s_n=6s_{n-1}-s_{n-2};\;s_0=2;\;s_1=6$$
If we rewrite the recurrence $\text{mod }5$ we get
$$s'_n=s'_{n-1}-s'_{n-2};\;s'_0=2;\;s'_1=1$$
which gives the values $\text{mod }5$ of the recurrence above.

The solution can be easily found by the characteristic equation
$$x^2-x+1=0\to x_1=\frac{1-i \sqrt{3}}{2};\;x_2=\frac{1+i \sqrt{3}}{2}$$
so we have
$$s'_n=a \left(\frac{1-i \sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^n + b\left(\frac{1+i \sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^n$$
Plugging the initial values $s'_0=2;\;s'_1=1$ we get
$$\begin{cases}
a+b=2\\
\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}\right) a+\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}\right) b=1\\
\end{cases}
$$
Solution is $a=1;\;b=1$ therefore the solution of the second recurrence is
$$s'_n= \left(\frac{1-i \sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^n + \left(\frac{1+i \sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^n$$
These are the numbers of the set $a^n+b^n$ modulus $5$ and can be easily seen that they are never $0$.

Finally we can say that $a^n+b^n$ is never divisible by $5$.